# conflict between websocket and httpinvoker

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, httpinvoker

we've a spring app with httpinvoker services. We've added websocket and now, our httpinvoker services becomes unavailable.
Do you know where it can comes from ?

Answer : the problem was not Websocket but a problem of configuration of two different DispatcherServlet

Comment: Ok, got an error? Maybe you can share your config file / piece of code with us...

Comment: In our web.xml we've defined 2 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet with two different mappings, one for /ws/* (httpinvoker) and /web/* (websocket)

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the cause and solution for this?